# Error #Valor en funcion de excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy creando una formula cual al escribir un numero llamado RTN me devulve el un nombre luego de una consulta web, por ejemplo pongo el numero 08019002275485 en la casilla RTN y me devuelve los resultados del cual necesito el nombre "EMPRESA DE CONSULTORIA EN INGIENERIA CONSULTING S DE R L"

El codigo vba es el siguiente

```
Function Registro(RTN As String)
   Dim IE As Object
   Dim Respuesta As String

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://enlacertn.sar.gob.hn"
    IE.Visible = True
   While IE.busy
    DoEvents
   Wend
   IE.document.All.Item("txtCriterio").Value = RTN
   IE.document.All("btnBuscar").Click
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

   Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
   Loop
   Respuesta = IE.document.getElementById("LblNombre").innertext
   Registro = Respuesta
  IE.Quit
End Function
```

necesito extraer el elemento **Id=LblNombre** pero me devulve un error la funcion

Adjunto imagenes para mayor comprension

[image: Excel Error]

[image: Antes dela consulta]

[image: Despues de la consulta]

[image: codigo de la pagina web]

Si son tan amables de indicarme donde tengo el error en la formula y de paso explicarme un poco como seria el codigo para aprender.

Gracias!

Comment: por favor mira [ask]. Las imagenes deberian estar en la pregunta. Y cual es el valor de la celda? porque el codigo parece hacer todo bien.

Comment: Si lo lei, tratare de leerlo de nuevo para corregir los errores, en una celda pongo el numero RTN y en otra la funcion registro de manera que me devuelva el nombre  que esta registrado de ese numero RTN.

Comment: pero esa funcion no devuelve nada...

Comment: Exacto, algo de la estructura del codigo de la pagina web o del codigo vba debe estar mal..

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que la funcion esta devolviendo un innertext, que vos comprobaste que estuviera bien?

Comment: no he comprobado nada, estuve buscando info sobre como extraer de un id, pero nada mas.

Comment: hasta que no lo pruebes.. es un error no reproducible.

Comment: Como lo prueba, soy nuevo en lo de las macros de excel y he estado aprendiendo de la web pero no se a que refieres con probar... si me explicas un poco mas para entender

Comment: Seguro hay montones de tutoriales por ahi que te pueden ayudar, no es algo que te pueda explicar en dos pasos, pero necesitas hacer un seguimiento linea por linea.. ejecutar paso a paso. pone un punto de quiebre al principio de la funcion y fijate que tiene cada objeto y que pasa en cada paso, a ver donde esta ocurriendo el problema.

Comment: Cuando de interactúa con la web estamos expuestos a tiempos de respuesta desconocidos. La función está "bien" pero los tiempos de espera con .wait no.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes usted que esperar a que la página se cargue con `While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend`. No utilizar como una función definida por el usuario. Es ineficiente. Llamar a la función desde un sub.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim RTN As String
    RTN = "08019002275485"
    Activesheet.Range("A1") =  Registro(RTN)
End Sub

Function Registro(ByVal RTN As String) As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://enlacertn.sar.gob.hn"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.all.item("txtCriterio").Value = RTN
        .document.all("btnBuscar").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

         Registro = .document.getElementById("LblNombre").innerText
        .Quit
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Se trata de un problema de tiempos. La función **Application.Wait** no está haciendo bien su trabajo porque solo funciona cuando es llamada desde un Sub/Macro. Puede estar en una función pero si llamas a esta desde una celda en la forma ***=Registro(A1)*** o desde el VBA (Ejecutar o F5) **Application.Wait** no realizará ningún tipo de delay, al menos programado, porque lógicamente el motor de Excel debe procesarla y eso lleva tiempo (*milisegundos*). Es fácil comprobar esto si ejecutamos en un *Sub* y en una *Function* el siguiente código:

```
MsgBox Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
```

Devolverá **Verdadero** y **Falso** respectivamente. **Application.Wait** funcionará bien, siempre y cuando esté dentro de una Sub/Macro (Sub y Macro son exactamente lo mismo) o cuando, si está en una función, sea llamada desde una Sub/Macro.

Debido a esto se genera un error cuando llegamos a las líneas:

```
IE.document.All("btnBuscar").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

Ya que tras ejecutar **.Click** deberiamos esperar a que el servidor encuentre el dato y sea mostrado en el navegador. Con un delay correcto, **.Click** devuelve perfectamente el valor y por lo tanto la función también.

Aunque lo de **.Wait** esté solucionado podría ocurrir, y de hecho ocurre con bastante frecuencia, que la línea:

```
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

genere un error por no haber podido crear el objeto y por consiguiente la función nos devolveria **#¡VALOR!**. En ese caso ya no es problema de los delays y para solucionarlo utlilizaremos **On Error Goto** junto con un contador para evitar un bucle cerrado.

El código siguiente funciona perfectamente aunque es posible que haya que ajustar los tiempos. Tampoco hace falta que **IE.Visible** sea ***True***.
Y si sale el famoso **#¡VALOR!** hay que volver a ejecutar la función ya que seguro que es por culpa de IE o los Delays.

```
Public Function Registro(RTN As String) As String
On Error GoTo otra

Dim IE As Object
Dim v_Time As Date
Dim v_ErrorCount As Integer
v_ErrorCount = 0
    'Delay incorrecto si no se llama desde Sub
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

otra:
    If v_ErrorCount > 2 Then    'Se puede aumentar el margen
        Registro = "Error en Set IE"
        Exit Function
    End If
    v_ErrorCount = v_ErrorCount + 1
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://enlacertn.sar.gob.hn"
    IE.Visible = False

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.document.All.Item("txtCriterio").Value = RTN
    IE.document.All("btnBuscar").Click
    f_Delay "00:00:03" 'Si falla mucho cambiar a 4 segundos
    Registro = IE.document.getElementById("LblNombre").innertext
    IE.Quit

    'Línea que muestra los intentos. Se puede eliminar
    MsgBox "Intentos " & v_ErrorCount
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function f_Delay(ByVal v_Delay As String)
    v_Time = Now
    Do While Now - v_Time < TimeValue(v_Delay)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function
```

Si vamos a utilizar un **Sub** para llamar a la función recuerda pasarle el dato RTN como argumento. Las siguientes funciones corren perfectamente.

```
Sub s_call2()

    'obj_Cell Almacena número RTN.
    Cells(obj_CellDestino) = Registro(obj_Cell.Value)

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function Registro(RTN As String) As String

Dim IE As Object
Dim Respuesta As String
Dim v_Time As Date

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://enlacertn.sar.gob.hn"
    IE.Visible = False

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    IE.document.All.Item("txtCriterio").Value = RTN
    IE.document.All("btnBuscar").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Registro = IE.document.getElementById("LblNombre").innertext
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    IE.Quit
End Function
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]